# Jssor playTo() in looped carousel

Tags: javascript, jssor

I have a simple problem with the playTo() method of Jssor. I have a carousel with multiple images in loop. I use playTo() method so that clicked image is moved to the center of the carousel.

There is a problem with this however. When and image is clicked from the "new batch" of images (that is an image after the last one, when the loop starts again), the carousel rewinds instead of choosing the the shortest route.

For example, I click one image to the right (which is actually the first loaded again in the loop), the playTo() methods rewinds the carousel all the way to the beggining (where the images original position is) instead of simply moving one step to the right.

The next() and prev() methods work correctly. When the last image is loaded and next() is called, the carousel simply moves one step to the right. If I used playTo(), the carousel would instead rewind all the way to the first image.

I couldn't find anything about this in documentation or stack overflow. Is there a way to force playTo() to move the carousel to the closest instance of chosen slide (either rewind or go forward to it's position in the next loop)? If not, this would be a welcome feature, as it seems pretty logical behaviour.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please compare the distance to go manually.

```
var targetIndex = yourIndex; //yourIndex is the index that you determined to go according to the image clicked.
var currentIndex = jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex();
var slidesCount = jssor_slider1.$SlidesCount();

if(targetIndex < currentIndex) {
    if(currentIndex - targetIndex > slidesCount - currentIndex) {
        targetIndex += slidesCount;
    }
}
else {
    if(targetIndex - currentIndex > slidesCount - currentIndex) {
        targetIndex -= slidesCount;
    }
}

jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(targetIndex);
```